# How can I detect a double tap on UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitabbaritem

I've tried adding a gesture recogniser, not realising that it isn't possible with a UITabBarItem, here is what I did: 
[image]

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will have a simple solution, as double tapping a tab bar item is not expected behavior. Even if you got it working, I would assume Apple would not pass the review, as it will likely go against their design guidelines.

Comment: Aha :/ Oh well, guess i'll have to rethink that, i could probably find another way rather than using double tap, anyways thank u!

Comment: The IMDb app has a double tap on the search tab bar item which gives focus to the search text view and pulls up the keyboard. Apple should allow this if they did for them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see that error whenever you try to add a gesture recognizer to an object that doesn't inherit from UIView. Try adding the gesture recognizer to the UITabBar and then using the point where the double tap occurred, matching it to the correct tab bar item.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution can be like this.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    let name = viewController.tabBarItem.title ?? ""
    if(name == "Home"){

        if(name == self.selectedTabName){
            print("tapped home again")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "scrollToTop"), object: nil)
        }
    }
    self.selectedTabName = name
    self.delay(0.5){

        self.selectedTabName = ""
    }

}
 func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
```